# Value restriction with type annotations without explicit function argument in F#

Tags: f#

I've been trying to get rid of explicit arguments in the following F# function:

```
let mapToSelf (s: seq<'a>): seq<'a> = s |> Seq.map id
```

This version with an explicit argument `s` has inferred type `seq<'a> -> seq<'a>` as expected, and I can use it for mapping over sequences of different types:

```
let stringSeq = mapToSelf [ "asd"; "qwe" ]
let intSeq = mapToSelf [ 1; 2; 3 ]
```

So far, so good. Now I would like to remove the explicit function argument `s` as follows, which I (erroneously?) expect to be equivalent to the first version:

```
let mapToSelf: (seq<'a> -> seq<'a>) = Seq.map id
```

Now I get a warning on this line:

```
let stringSeq = mapToSelf [ "asd"; "qwe" ]
// The construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by the type annotations
```

And en error on the next line, since the function now has the signature `(seq<string> -> seq<string>)`:

```
let intSeq = mapToSelf [ 1; 2; 3 ]
// The expression was expected to have type 'string', but here was type 'int'
```

My question is: why is the generic type signature I specify myself `seq<'a> -> seq<'a>` gets overridden by a less generic `seq<string> -> seq<string>`? And is there a way to declare such a function without explicitly specifying the argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to decorate the binding with a generic type:

```
> let mapToSelf<'T> : seq<'T> -> seq<'T> = Seq.map id;;
val mapToSelf<'T> : (seq<'T> -> seq<'T>)

> mapToSelf [| 1; 2 |];;
val it : seq<int> = seq [1; 2]
> mapToSelf [ "1"; "2" ];;
val it : seq<string> = seq ["1"; "2"]
```

> why is the generic type signature I specify myself `seq<'a> -> seq<'a>` gets overridden by a less generic `seq<string> -> seq<string>`?

With no function arguments to type-generalize, the compiler is inferring its type from the first usage.

Comment: Yep, that was it. The funny thing is that I actually tried it (I thought I did), but without a space between `seq<'a>` and `:`. Well, just when you thought you've figured out F# syntax... ;) Thanks for the help!